# How to click link (menu) to open tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I trying to click link from menu to open tabs(div) but I cannot find solutions.

```
<div>   
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs1" class="select">tabs1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs2">tabs2</a></li>   
  </ul> 
</div>

<div id="tabs1" class="active"></div>
<div id="tabs2"></div>
```

It not work when I open form 1.html (not have tabs) and click menu to to open tabs2 in 2.html. Any Ideas? Thanks !

**Update** - This is my script.

```
$("a#tabs-1").click(function () {
    $("a#tabs-2").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
$("a#tabs-2").click(function () {
    $("a#tabs-1").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: are you using any tab plugins

Comment: Are you using jQuery Tabs for this ? ( http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ ) or do you wanna write your own little script ? Either way, we need to see some code. Not just HTML...

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/,
google has a lot of resources

Answer (score 2):

It is the simplest code with the simplest CSS I could provide for you. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5j09Lota/).

```js
$(".tabs1").click(function () {
    $("#tabs2").removeClass("active");
    $("#tabs1").addClass("active");
});
$(".tabs2").click(function () {
    $("#tabs1").removeClass("active");
    $("#tabs2").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
#tabs1, #tabs2 {
    display: none;
}
#tabs1.active, #tabs2.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>   
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs1" class="select tabs1">tabs1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs2" class="tabs2">tabs2</a></li>   
  </ul> 
</div>

<div id="tabs1" class="active">tab1</div>
<div id="tabs2">tab2</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It not work when I open form 1.html (not have tabs) and click menu to to open tabs2 in 2.html. Any Ideas? Thanks !

Comment: @Mrronalz In your menu there are links to open tab1 and tab2 from another page? I'm not quite getting what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```js
$('.tabs li').click(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
    $tab = $($this.find('a').attr('href'));
  $this.addClass('select');
  $this.siblings().removeClass('select');
  $tab.show().addClass('active');
  $('.tab').not($tab).hide().removeClass('active');

  e.preventDefault();
}).filter(':has(.select)').click();
```

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>   
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tabs1" class="select">tabs1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs2">tabs2</a></li>   
  </ul> 
</div>

<div id="tabs1" class="tab active">tabs1</div>
<div id="tabs2" class="tab">tabs2</div>
```

Comment: That's actually better than mine. I didn't pay attention for the `select` class the `<a>` element has. +1

Answer (score 0):

I have added a class `tabsDiv` to the `div`, To make it go smooth.

```
<div>   
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs1" class="select">tabs1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs2">tabs2</a></li>   
  </ul> 
</div>

<div id="tabs1" class="tabsDiv active"></div>
<div id="tabs2" class="tabsDiv"></div>
```

When you click on a `a` just add `class` `select` to that particular `a` and remove this class from all its siblings. And then fetch `href` of the clicked `a` and make the `div` with `id` of that `href` `active`.

Dont forget to add `e.stopProagation()` to halt the default behavior of clicking on `a` tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div ul li a").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        $(this).addClass("select").siblings("a").removeClass("select");
        var _toOpen = this.href;
        $(".tabsDiv").removeClass("active");
        $(_toOpen).addClass("active");
    });

});
```